# Problems casting a double into an unsigned char

Tags: c

Why does casting a double 728.3 to an unsigned char produce zero? 728 is 0x2D8, so shouldn't `w` be `0xD8` (`216`)?

```
int w = (unsigned char)728.3;
int x = (int)728.3;
int y = (int)(unsigned char)728.3;
int z = (unsigned char)(int)728.3;
printf( "%i %i %i %i", w, x, y, z );

// prints 0 728 0 216
```

Comment: Out of range -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: Use `int w = (unsigned char)(unsigned long long)728.3;`

Comment: @chux: Why using a sledgehammer to crack a nut? `(unsigned char)(unsigned int)728.3` is sufficient. Not sure why you use `inmt w`, though. Wasn't `unsigned char` the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the C standard 6.3.1.4p1:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). **If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined**.

So, unless you have >=10 bit `unsigned char`, your code invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Note that the cast explicitly tells the compiler you know what you are doing, thus suppresses a warning.

Comment: Thanks. What's interesting is that I get no compiler warning, even with -Wpedantic on (Xcode 8.3.2 / llvm).

Comment: @EricS: Try `-Wconversion` (which is recommended anyway), it works for integers, not sure about floats. However, there is no need for a diagnostic.

Comment: @EricS that is because the casts defeat the compiler warnings, and is one reason why casts are dangerous.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Good point. I added this to the answer, if you don't mind :-)

Comment: Pleased you agree!

Comment: No warning even with `-Wconversion`. I would think with a constant value the compiler could be smart enough to give a warning, but I guess not.

Comment: @EricS: Yes, I thought about it after WeatherVanes comment; he is right. And technically there is no constant, but an expression. The standard does not specify when it is evaluated. An exception just for this special case is quite useless. That's why one should use casts **iff** 1) absolutely necessary and 2) all implications are understood and 3) are fully acepted.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that `unsigned char` has 8 value bits, as is nearly (but not completely) certain for your implementation, the behavior of converting the `double` value 728.3 to type `unsigned char` is undefined, as specified by [paragraph 6.3.1.4/1 of the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.4p1):

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer
>   type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the
>   value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part
>   cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

This applies to both your `w` and your `y`.  It does not apply to your `x`, and the rules covering conversions between integer values (i.e. your `z`) are different.

Basically, then, there is no answer at the C level for why you see the specific results you do, nor for why I see different ones when I run your code.  The behavior is *undefined*; I can be thankful that it did not turn out to be an outpouring of nasal demons.